# Vue.js - Watcher for property with variable keypath

Tags: vuejs2

Is it possible, in Vue v2, to define a watcher using a keypath containing a variable?

For example, depending on the `currentKey`, I want to watch either the changes in `obj.A` or `obj.B`:

```
data() {
  return {
    currentKey: 'A',
    obj: { A: { 'a': '' }, B: { 'b' :'' },
  }
},
watch: {
  'obj[currentKey]'(newItem, oldItem) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a computed property which returns `this.obj[this.currentKey]` and then set a watcher on that.

But, if you want to watch changes to the properties of the dynamic object, you'll also need to set the `deep` property of the watcher to `true`.

Here's a simple example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      currentKey: 'A',
      obj: {A: {value: ''}, B: {value:''} },
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selected() {
      return this.obj[this.currentKey];
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selected: {
      deep: true,
      handler(object) {
     console.log('selected object value', object.value);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Selected object: {{ selected }}
  <select v-model="currentKey">
    <option v-for="i in ['A', 'B']" :key="i" :value="i">{{ i }}</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  Text for selected object: <input v-model="selected.value">   
</div>
```